# Python Functions Error

Tags: python

First time posting. So my Python class assignment has me creating a program to calculate Miles Per Gallon and then print whether the MPG was good or not. So here are the requirements:

This program will go further by testing a total of 4 cars, will do data validation on the user input, and will utilize functions to do the work.
There will be a total of 7 functions:  `main(), printWelcome(), getMiles(), getGallons(), calcMpg(), printMpg(), and rateMpg()`
The functions will perform as follows:

```
main()
```

•   Will have no parameters (i.e. an empty parameter list)
•   Will call the `printWelcome()` function
•   Will then have a loop to run 4 times, that will do the following
o   Call on `getMiles()`
o   Call on `getGallons()` 
o   Call on `calcMpg()`
o   Call on `printMpg()`
o   Call on `rateMpg()`
o   The above steps will involve more code than just a method call, but what is needed is left for you to determine

```
printWelcome()
```

•   Will have no parameters
•   Will print out the Welcome message used previously

```
getMiles()
```

•   Will have no parameters
•   Will ask for the integer number of miles from the user
•   Will do data validation to ensure that the miles are > 0
•   Once you have good data, will return the number of miles, i.e. the user input, back to the calling function

```
getGallons()
```

•   Will have no parameters
•   Will ask for the integer number of gallons from the user
•   Will do data validation to ensure that the gallons are > 0
•   Once you have good data, will return the number of gallons, i.e. the user input, back to the calling function

```
calcMpg()
```

•   Will have 2 parameters – one for the number of miles and one for the number of gallons
•   Will calculate the mpg and then return that value

```
printMpg()
```

•   Will have 1 parameter, the value of the mpg
•   Will print that value, must be formatted to how only 3 places after the decimal
•   Does not return any new information

```
rateMpg()
```

•   Will have 1 parameter, the value of the mpg
•   Will print out a message indicating how good the mpg is based on the following criteria:
•   For mpg less than 12, will print "Poor mpg."
•   For mpg between 12 (inclusive) and 19 (inclusive), will print "Fair mpg."
•   For mpg between 20 (inclusive) and 26 (inclusive), will print "Good mpg."
•   For mpg greater than 26, will print "Excellent mpg."
Here is my code:

```
def main():
    printWelcome()
    getMiles()
    getGallons()
    calMPG()
    printMPG()
    rateMPG()

def printWelcome():
    print ("Welcome to my Miles Per Gallon program")

def getMiles():
    miles = int(input('How many miles did you drive? '))
    while miles < 0:
     print("Number cannot be negative. Try again.")
     miles = int(input('How many miles did you drive? '))
    return miles

def getGallons():
    gals = int(input('How many gallons of gas did you use? '))
    while gals < 0:
     print("Number cannot be negative. Try again.")
     gals = int(input('How many gallons of gas did you use? '))
    return gals

def calMPG(miles, gals):
    MPG = miles / gals
    return MPG

def printMPG(MPG):
    print("Your MPG is", \
       format(MPG, '.3f'))

def rateMPG(MPG):
    if MPG < 12:
        print("Poor MPG")
    elif MPG >= 12 and MPG <= 19:
        print("Fair MPG")
    elif MPG >= 19 and MPG <= 26:
         print("Good MPG")
    elif MPG < 26:
        print("Excellent MPG")



main()
```

This is the error that pops up:
`calMPG()` **missing 2 required positional arguments: 'miles' and 'gals'**

Why do i need 2 required arguments? `calMPG` has 2 parameters. I'm confused by this error. I really feel like this is something super easy but for the life of me the answer is dodging me tonight. Any feedback is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: U must call function with passed parameters. Something like calMPG(1, 2). Moreover, you have the same problem with other functions.

Comment: You seem like a newbie to programming. When you call any function, you need to pass the defined parameters to it. This is applicable to basically any programming language. For now read [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm) to understand calling/defining a function in python.

Answer (score 0):

in your main 
you are calling calMPG with no params
you can change your code as follow

```
def calMPG(miles=None, gals=None):
    if miles and gals:
        MPG = miles / gals
        return MPG
```

Comment: Thanks. Now its saying "Miles not defined". Interesting

Comment: you can even pass None, None as callMPG(None, None) in main if you don't want to make above change but then you will have to handle None values inside function

Answer (score 0):

Since you're calling functions that return the values, you need to store them somewhere. Since you're not storing them anywhere the data is lost within the local scope of each of the functions, meaning the functions are being called the values are being returned discarded as they aren't being assigned anywhere. Also as [Kuldeep K. Rishi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2202381/kuldeep-k-rishi) said, you're also calling functions without the parameters that you're defining them to take. The fix should be as follows. *Tested in pycharm*

```
def main():
    printWelcome()
    miles = getMiles()
    gals = getGallons()
    mpg = calMPG(miles, gals)
    printMPG(mpg)
    rateMPG(mpg)

def printWelcome():
    print ("Welcome to my Miles Per Gallon program")

def getMiles():
    miles = int(input('How many miles did you drive? '))
    while miles < 0:
     print("Number cannot be negative. Try again.")
     miles = int(input('How many miles did you drive? '))
    return miles

def getGallons():
    gals = int(input('How many gallons of gas did you use? '))
    while gals < 0:
     print("Number cannot be negative. Try again.")
     gals = int(input('How many gallons of gas did you use? '))
    return gals

def calMPG(miles, gals):
    MPG = miles / gals
    return MPG

def printMPG(MPG):
    print("Your MPG is", \
       format(MPG, '.3f'))

def rateMPG(MPG):
    if MPG < 12:
        print("Poor MPG")
    elif MPG >= 12 and MPG <= 19:
        print("Fair MPG")
    elif MPG >= 19 and MPG <= 26:
         print("Good MPG")
    elif MPG < 26:
        print("Excellent MPG")

main()
```

A slightly optimized version of calling the functions that wouldn't require you storing as many variables would be with this change of the main function which is as follows.

```
def main():
    printWelcome()
    mpg = calMPG(getMiles(), getGallons())
    printMPG(mpg)
    rateMPG(mpg)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I had gotten rid of these earlier:  " miles = getMiles()
    gals = getGallons()
    mpg = calMPG(miles, gals)"  I appreciate it